# LockIn Amplifier Noise measurement

Tags: amplifier, noise, frequency-measurement

On my understanding, a LockIn amplifier use an internal (or external) signal source, set to a given frequency, say x. The system locks into that frequency, which means only that frequency can be analyzed by the device.
Is it right, that when the device is „locked“ on that frequency x, I could measure voltage noise of an amplifier (with shorted inputs, high noise amplification) on that frequency x. To get the whole frequency noise response, (1/f + white noise) I would need the setup to do a frequency sweep?

Comment: [Wikipedia on lock-in amplifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-in_amplifier). Have you read this? Have you tried to find this out yourself?

Answer (score 1):

If you can view the lockon amplifier's detector as a multiplier/lowpass, then you have a Correlation Filter.

So yes, by stepping the external reference frequency (to which the weak signal is expected have the same frequency), you can  analyse the passband shape.